# Issue with tabularx and pgfplotstable when specifying column type

Tags: tabularx, pgfplotstable

I am having trouble using a tabularx environment together with the pgfplotstable package. As soon as I specify a column type in tabularx, I recieve a series of errors. When no column type is specified the code runs through. Needless to say that I am using tabularx to specify column types ;-)

Any help is appreciated!

```latex
% minimal example 

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{filecontents*}{dummyData.csv}
median,Q1,Q3,IQR,QGR2,QGR3,mean,std,N
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% doesn't work
\pgfplotstableset{ 
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXXXXX},
    end table=\end{tabularx}    
}

% works
%\pgfplotstableset{ 
%   begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
%       end table=\end{tabularx}    
%}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = comma,
    every column/.style={fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1,dec sep align},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    string type
    ]{dummyData.csv}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The example code works if you add `column type=,` to `\pgfplotstableset`  and if you remove `every column/.style={fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1,dec sep align},` from `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I played around with it a bit more and the bad guy seems to be the `dec sep align`. Once I remove that (and add `column type=,` in `\pgfplotstableset`), It runs through fine. Could it be the aligning from tabularx and the `dec sep align` are incompatible? Anyway, thanks a lot @leandriis:-)